# How to check if a new node is correctly created using Entity Metadata Wrapper $wrapper->save()?

Tags: 7, entities

I'm programmatically creating a new node using Entity Metadata Wrapper.

How to check if last instruction:

```
$ewrapper->save();
```

creates correctly the new node without errors?

Comment: how about simpletest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that the entity has an identifier:

```
if ($ewrapper->getIdentifier()) {
  // Save happened.
}
```

A better approach might be handling any errors:

```
try {
  $ewrapper->save();

  // Try to do something with $ewrapper->getIdentifier()
}
catch (\Exception $e) {
  // Recover...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to chech the following: `$wrapper->getIdentifier()`, it should return nid of new node.